# Creating a message box in Excel FROM Access

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

My database is controlling the creation and manipulation of Excel spreadsheets and then presenting them to the user to save. However, I have found that users are pressing cancel on the save dialogue which means they effectively are still in the template sheet.

I've gotten round this by adding a loop, but want to prompt the user after cancel with a message "you need to save this sheet" before presenting the Save dialogue box again. However, when I do 
    `MsgBox "You must save this file!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Save Error"`
the box is shown in Access, rather than Excel. Surely there must be a way to reference Excel, but I've tried 
    `appxl.MsgBox "You must save this file!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Save Error"`
and got nowhere. (Obviously my referencing the Excel application is all A-OK elsewhere as the sheets work fine).

Is there a way to trigger a message box in a controlled application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the vbSystemModal to the MsgBox

```
appxl.MsgBox "You must save this file!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly + vbSystemModal, "Save Error"
```

Comment: many thanks. That worked, although for completeness I should say that I didn't need to reference the excel app, using only `MsgBox` rather than `appxl.MsgBox` which throws an exception.

Comment: Thanks @GavinP.  It may have caused an error because the MsgBox seems to work independent of the application object. I appreciate your clarification.